# Have biblatex reference numbers match the footnote numbers

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex

I want to use biblatex so that I can use `\footcite` in a normal text, which generates a footnote that has a bit of information in it.

The rest of the information should be in the section generated by `printbibliography`.

The problem is that the numbers next to the reference entries don't match the numbering of the footnotes, which is extremely confusing.

So in my working copy the reference number in the `printbibliography` section should be: **3** for the "*Darnassus et al*" entry and **1** for the "*The Bad Wolf*" entry.

How can I do this? I know there would be trouble when referencing to the same entry, but this could be solved by just reusing the same footnote number.

If this looks like a very bad idea, please tell me. It's my first time using a bibliography, so I might be misconceived on how to use it.

### Working copy:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle-ibid,bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

    @misc{Darn,
        title={A strange scribling},
        author={Dr. Darnassus and others},
        year= {1820},
    }

    @book{DKB,
        title={Three little pigs},
        author={The bad wolf},
        year={1999},
    }

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

An overly\footcite[][33]{DKB} footnoted\footnote{a normal footnote} sentence\footcite{Darn}
\newpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understood what you want to do. Please correct me if I'm wrong: Assuming you have a footnote like `3 Darnassus et al., A strange scribling.` this entry should be numbered in the bibliography like in the footnote. If you want to do so I think it's a really bad idea. How do you want to handle it, when you have more than one work in a footnote like this: `3 Darnassus et al., A strange scribling; Testauthor, Another Work`. So both entries would get the same number which would be really confusing.

Comment: This is a very unorthodox citation system, and as Thorsten says, it will lead to problems. You should find out what citation system is used in your field of study and use that system, rather than invent one on your own.

Comment: I think the OP (correct me if I'm wrong) wants something like the reference style the journal _Nature_, where the citations are indicated by superscript numbers that correspond to entries in the bibliography at the end of the article.  The difference is that OP also wants some kind of in-page note giving a few details.  This seems somewhat non-standard, but maybe something could be hacked together with a numeric citation style plus `\footnotemark`/`\footnotetext`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this does the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric,bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\long\def\mycitefootnote[#1]#2{\begingroup
\def\thefootnote{#1}\footnote[1]{#2}\endgroup}

\long\def\myfootcitemark#1{\begingroup
\def\thefootnote{\cite{#1}}\footnotemark[2]\endgroup}

\newcommand\myfootcite[1]{\mycitefootnote[\cite{#1}]{\citetitle{#1}, \citeauthor{#1}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

    @misc{Darn,
        title={A strange scribling},
        author={Dr. Darnassus and others},
        year= {1820},
    }

    @book{DKB,
        title={Three little pigs},
        author={Wolf, The Bad},
        year={1999},
    }

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a test\myfootcite{DKB} phrase,\footnote{a footnote} which contains\myfootcite{Darn} several cites, and footnotes intertwined\myfootcitemark{Darn} 

\newpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

In fact, I don't think the output is that confusing. Although I may switch to something more orthodox.

---

Of course I would have to add some more functionality, late prenote text etc...